# ReactNative: App crash when i'm using react-native fcm

Tags: react-native

When i'm using react-native fcm my app get crash without no error

here's my dependency

```
dependencies {

    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
  }
```

and package.json

```
"react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-fcm": "^16.2.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
```

please any one help me

Comment: Can you add AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes add service and receiver tags also the user permissions

Comment: you can get crash logs in android studio.please post that, there must be issue with versions of fcm and google-play-service

Comment: use this https://rnfirebase.io/ library instead of react-native-fcm